# SQL Query - Improvement Needed

Tags: sql

I have written an extremely ugly SQL Query and to be honest I am quite embarrassed to post it here... But I need some help regarding the 4 SELECT statements that are the same. Is there a better way to do this without creating that table?

I am not sure if the contents of the huge SELECT is relevant to answering this question. In case it is, I will try to put that query up. (But since I highly simplified the entire example that might be quite difficult to do).

Any help is very much appreciated.

(This question is a follow-up to another question I had asked here: [Comparing "Consecutive" Rows in Ms Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889951/comparing-consecutive-rows-in-ms-access) )

```
SELECT t2.* FROM 
  (SELECT t.ID, t.SubID, t.Time, t.Value, t.value2, t.value
   FROM
```

(
HUGE SELECT HERE with 3 joins) t

```
   WHERE t.Time=4)  AS t2 
           LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT t.ID, t.SubID, t.Time, t.Value, t.value2, t.value
    FROM
```

(
HUGE SELECT HERE with 3 joins) t

```
    WHERE t.Time=3)  AS t1 
         ON t2.Id = t1.Id
         WHERE t2.value<>t1.value
         OR t2.value2<>t1.value2 
         OR t1.Id Is Null
```

UNION ALL

```
   SELECT t1.* FROM
   (SELECT t.ID, t.SubID, t.Time, t.Value, t.value2, t.value
    FROM
```

(
HUGE SELECT HERE with 3 joins) t

```
     WHERE t.Time=3) AS t1
           LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT t.ID, t.SubID, t.Time, t.Value, t.value2, t.value
    FROM
```

(
HUGE SELECT HERE with 3 joins) t

```
    WHERE t.Time=4) AS t2
          ON t1.Id=t2.Id
          WHERE t1.value<>t2.value
         OR t1.value2<>t2.value2 
          OR t2.Id Is Null
```

ORDER BY Id, EntryNo;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to simplify this to something like:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.SubID, t1.Time, t1.Value, t1.value2, t1.value FROM
```

( HUGE SELECT HERE with 3 joins) t1

```
LEFT JOIN
```

( HUGE SELECT HERE with 3 joins) t2

```
     ON ( t2.Id = t1.Id AND t1.Time <> t2.Time and T2.Time in (3,4) )
     WHERE T1.Time in (3,4) and
           (t2.value<>t1.value OR t2.value2<>t1.value2 OR t2.Id Is Null)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. So there is truly no way to only write the "huge select with 3 joins" once?

Comment: @taranaki: (Not sure how I missed this comment earlier.) Not in MS Access (as far as I know) - other dialects of SQL (including SQLServer) have something called Common Table Expressions (CTEs) but these are not available in Access.

Comment: hi, no problem. Glad you saw it now :). Well, two selects are still better than 4 :) So thanks a lot for your help.